# Check if two graphs are edge-disjoint

Tags: graphs, depth-first-search, disjoint-sets

> Two undirected graphs $G$ and $H$ on the vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$ are disjoint if the intersection of
> their edge sets is empty.
> Assume  both  $G$  and  $H$  are  represented  by  adjacency  matrices.
>
> Describe  an  efficient
> algorithm that decides if $G$ and $H$ are disjoint.  What is the complexity of your algorithm?
> Justify the correctness of your algorithm and your complexity claim.

What I am thinking is just picking an arbitrary vertex on either graph like $G$ and checking if we can reach a vertex from the other graph $H$ by running some simple traversal like DFS. Is there a better way? I am thinking what if we go through the adjacency matrix of one graph and check if any edge connects a vertex from one graph to the other.

Comment: It seems to me that you have not really understood what it means that graphs are disjoints. Please re-read the definition. It is a good idea to use the adjacency matrix, but what does it mean that a edge connects a vertex from one graph to the other?

Comment: @Nathaniel isn't exactly what you said an edge connecting one vertex from one graph to the other? I am confused

Comment: Graphs may be edge disjoint and vertex disjoint, and your definition describes edge disjoint ones. So, they might have common vertices and your idea with DFS won't work.

Comment: so what is a better way?

Comment: As an example, you could have $E_G = \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}\}$ and $E_H = \{\{2, 3\}, \{4, 5\}, \{6, 7\}\}$. This is an example of two disjoint graphs, because they have no edge in common. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

The adjacency matrix $A_G$ of an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined as follows: $A_G$ is a $V \times V$ matrix, $A_G(v,v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$, and $A_G(u,v) = 1$ if $\{u,v\} \in E$ and $A_G(u,v) = 0$ if $\{u,v\} \notin E$.

Two graphs $G,H$ are edge-disjoint if there doesn't exist an edge $\{u,v\}$ which belongs to both of them. That is, $G,H$ are edges-disjoint if there do no exist $u,v$ such that $A_G(u,v) = A_H(u,v) = 1$.

You take it from here.